# Travel distance of a particle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

How can we show that a projectile fired at an angle $\theta$ with initial speed $v_0$ travels a total distance $\frac{v_0^2}{g}\sin2\theta$ before hitting the ground?
The way I set it up is: direction is $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. By using Newton's law, $$r(t) = (0,-\frac{1}{2} gt^2)+tv_0(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) = \frac{v_0^2}{g}\sin2\theta$$
I tried to solve the LHS so that it matches the RHS, the total distance. But obviously, there is something wrong with the way I tried to approach it. But cannot see it.

Any hints and pointers in terms of setting it up would be great. Also I do not want the full solution but rather few small hints to be able to set it up correctly.

Comment: The LHS is a vector, the RHS is a scalar... Instead, write the equation that gives the vertical displacement at time $t$: $r_V(t)=v_0(\sin\theta)t-(1/2)gt^2$. Find the time when this is $0$ again. Then use that to find the total distance traveled. I assume they meant "horizontal distance traveled". So you'll need to consider the horizontal component of $r$, here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find out how long it takes for the $y$-component of velocity to reach $0$.  Call that time $t_0$.

By symmetry it takes time $2t_0$ to hit the ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you have learned differential equation, you can represent the displacement ${\bf r}(t) = (r_1,r_2)$ by an initial value problem:
$${\bf r}''(t) = (0,-g)
\\
{\bf r} (0) = (0,0)
\\
{\bf r}'(0) = {\bf v}(0) = (v_0 \cos(\theta), v_0 \sin(\theta))
$$
solve the y component = zero for a time, then plugging it in the x component. This approach I learned in ODE class is good, for air friction fits perfectly for the model, gravitatiional constant change too :
$$
{\bf r}''(t) = (0,-\frac{GM}{(r_2+R)^2}) - \gamma {\bf r}'(t)
$$
$M$ is the mass of the earth and $R$ is the radius.